# Afterpay module not showing on frontend in magento 2 site

Tags: magento-2.1

We have installed the afterpay module in magento 2 site.

Properly fired the required command.

But afterpay not showing at checkout.

Back end showing fine configuration and I have properly configured details of it.

Comment: Have you check that is there any error into log file or consol?

Comment: Not found any error related afterpay

Comment: We have installed the afterpay module in magento 2 site. Properly fired the required command. But afterpay not showing at checkout. Back end showing fine configuration and I have properly configured details of it. please help me.